# Show/hide google Map icon when app in background

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi i wants to **hide/show map icon** when my activity/page in background/foreground.
i did not know how to do this because new in android so please reply as soon as possible.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you unregister the callbacks from google maps on your onPause.

Answer (score 2):

As you already call this `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)` in `onCreate` or in `setupMap`, you need to disable it in `onPause`

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mMap != null) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: This also happens to be the workaround for a known [memory leak](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8111).