# Location icon does not always disappear when app is minimized on Android

Tags: google-maps, codenameone

I use Codename One to code my app. I've defined my UserLocationListener and use it successfully with the LocationManager.

In the main class' `stop` method I set `LocationManager.setLocationListener (null)` and the location icon disappears when the app is minimized.

However I'm also using a MapContainer with `setShowMyLocation (true)` and when the app gets minimized from a form that does not show the MapContainer the Location icon remains in the Android (Nougat) bar. Same behaviour when I get back to the form with the map from a form without it and then minimize the app.

Please note that if I don't `setShowMyLocation (true)` the icon disappears from whichever form.

Furthermore in the `stop` method I `setShowMyLocation (false)` but it looks like the listener does not stop.

What can I do to ensure that the location goes off when my app is minimized?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not call `setShowMyLocation(false)` on `stop()`?

Comment: But I did (see latest paragraph)! Actually I am using  `if (MainForm.map != null) {
           MainForm.map.setShowMyLocation(false);
        }`

Comment: Is it possible that this works but takes a few minutes to update the icon due to the call on the stop method?

Comment: You may be right indeed! If the user clicks on the home button, the location icon disappears immediately most of the time. But when the user switches from my app to another via the "recent app list" button then it takes much longer (if it finally disappears). I will check, for now more than 4 minutes have elapsed without the disappearing of the icon.

Comment: After more than three hours the location icon had not disappeared.

Comment: It looks like this is a bug in Google Maps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32316040/show-hide-google-map-icon-when-app-in-background